# what is the command for finding integer in a integer?

Tags: c++

for example I have a c++ which takes 2 integers from a file. For example int a = 2052342 and int b = 2. I need to do a search that will search if b is inside a. So in this example, b is inside a, but if b would be for example 7 it wouldn't be. What kind of function, should I use, and could you give me a quick demo of it? 
Edit: No it's not a homework, I will compete in Programmers Olympiad this year, so I'm programming all of the C++ exercises that were in last Programmers Olympiads.

Comment: That requirement is so artificial, it has to be homework. Is this, in fact, a learning exercise assigned by a teacher?

Comment: No it's not a homework, I will compete in Programmers Olympiad this year, so I'm programming all of the C++ exercises that were in last Programmers Olympiads.

Comment: Define what it means for a number to be "inside" of another. There is a reason there is no "inside of" operator...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a pretty flakey example without much explanation of what "if b is inside a' means. Are you just checking to see if the substring of 'int b' is inside 'int a'? if B were 205, or 234, would that count?

Perhaps not the best way, but simple enough, is to convert each integer to a string, and then do a substring check to see if stringB is a substring of stringA.

**Update:** Infact, when you're parsing your file, i'd just read them in as string, don't even look at this as a problem of integers. You're just doing substring checks. Also, if you parse them as integers, you'd run in to 0-padding being lost.

If you're talking about division or something else, that could be done by doing division.

Comment: Hello, Yes that will count. Ok will try to convert it to string.

Comment: you mean modulo instead of division?

Comment: @Moo, Not exactly sure what I meant since it would have been more complicated than a basic division or modulo. Moot now based on what the OP is saying, ehh?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is just to keep the numbers in their string
representation, and use `std::find`.  If you already have the numbers in
internal format, and converting them to a string would be too expensive:
`a % 10 == b` will be true if the low digit of `a` is equal to `b`, and 
`a /= 10` will remove the low digit.  So:

```
while ( a != 0 && a % 10 != b ) {
    a /= 10;
}
return a != 0;
```

should do the trick.